# Wedge product for composite of linear transformations

Tags: tensor-products, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

I am studying the wedge product for multivariable analysis, but I feel that the operations are not so intuitive in general. I am looking at the following question which deals with linear transformations.

Let $V,W,Z$ be vector spaces over a field $k$

If $f:V \rightarrow W$ and  $g:W \rightarrow Z$ are linear transformations. Prove that $\wedge ^r (g\circ f)=\wedge ^r(g)\circ \wedge ^r(f)$.

I've seen examples of linear transformation in $R^n$, and I think that this is either a little too simple and need only involve a basis for each vector space, or this is too messy to write. I tried to get a little more comfortable with the notation around this problem by making up an example with two different dimensions. I used a linear transformation such as

$T_1: R^2\rightarrow R^3$ defined by $T_1(x,y)=(x-y,x,y)$ and

$T_2: R^3\rightarrow R^3$ defined by $T_2(x,y,z)=(2x, 2z, y-x)$

and I considered r=2.

As a result I got the following:

$\wedge^2 f = \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           1 \\
           1
           \end{bmatrix}$

$\wedge^2 g = \begin{bmatrix}
           0 & 4 & 0 \\
           2 & 0 & 0 \\
           0 & 2 & -2
           \end{bmatrix}$

When I take the product of both matrices I get

$(\wedge^2 g) \circ (\wedge^2 f)= \begin{bmatrix}
                           4\\
                           2\\
                           0
                           \end{bmatrix}$

If instead I first take the composition and try to compute the wedge product also I get

$\wedge^2(g\circ f)= \begin{bmatrix}
                   4 \\
                   2 \\
                   0
                   \end{bmatrix}$

I just feel that I am not really manipulating the abstract generalized notion for the definition used over wedge products. I initially thought that maybe it might help to assume certain dimensions $l,m$ and $n$ for the vector spaces given and write out a basis for each of them, but yet when writing things out, I don't really know what else to do (the definition itself looks a little intimidating).

I appreciate any help given in order to understand a little more what is happening with the wedge product when considering an arbitrary $r$ and dealing with both linear transformations.